# PHP(AJAX) Files upload trouble w/$_FILES

Tags: php, ajax, configuration, nginx, apache2

Good day!
I've a trouble with my ajax file uploading algorithm. it is working fin on my local server( (**Apache2/PHP**), but when i use it in the remote server  (**Remote server:Nginx/PHP-FPM**) it is producing an error
`PHP side can't parse it: "Notice: Undefined index: fileselect ..." (Remote server:Nginx/PHP-FPM).`

In **php/nginx conf**, the file uploading config variables (like max size of uploaded files) are set to 5MB. Also i have given full access `chmod -R 775 dir` to the upload folder

help please.

P.s. I think it's configs, not code, 'coz code is work on local server

P.s.s. $_FILES - is empty

Comment: Look up `Notice: Undefined index:` - it's likely the error reporting level on your server. You need to turn that down, or fix the issue in the code

Comment: Can you rewrite that in English?

Comment: nginx/php-fpm cgi  and apache/mod-php are really different, show us configurations files, try to set an apache/php-fpm (and never use chmod 777).